# <function> is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit

Tags: typescript, angular9

tengo un formulario censillo y quiero que al hacer submit se ejecute una funcion pero la consola me tira el error del titulo

**inicio.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-inicio',
 templateUrl: './inicio.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./inicio.component.css']
})
export class InicioComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit(): void {

 }

 register(e): any{
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('hola')
 }

}
```

**inicio.component.html**

```
<form onsubmit="register()">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre/s">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos/s">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Usuarios">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="date">
        <select name="">
            <option value="hombre">Hombre</option>
            <option value="mujer">Mujer</option>
            <option value="indefinido">Prefiero no decirlo</option>
        </select>
        <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Confirme su contraseña">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-pill mt-2 w-50 ">Registrarme</button>
        <p><small>Al registrarse uested estara aceptando nuestros <a href="#">Terminos y condiciones</a></small></p>
    </form>
```

//les agradeceria mucho si me ayuda, es mi primera vez con angular, desde ya buenas noches.

Answer (score 1):

Debes modificar tu archivo .html para que te quede así. Creo que es por la directiva **ngSumit**

`<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="register(f)" >`

Y en tu archivo .ts te queda algo como esto:

`public register(f:NgForm){ //lo que quieras hacer }`

Te copio unos enlaces de un proy en github con algo parecido
[Html](https://github.com/cristian16b/Analisis-Bioq/blob/master/src/app/crear-obra-social/crear-obra-social.component.html)
[Ts](https://github.com/cristian16b/Analisis-Bioq/blob/master/src/app/crear-obra-social/crear-obra-social.component.ts)

Comment: tu método me funciono, muchísimas gracias

Comment: Buenisimo, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como solucionada.